# SELECT with Different WHERE Conditions

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I would like to run a select something like this.

```
SELECT
        COUNT(*) WHERE switch=0 AND detail=1 AS zeroone
    AND
        COUNT(*) WHERE switch=0 AND detail=2 AS zerotwo
    AND
        COUNT(*) WHERE switch=1 AND detail=1 AS oneone
    AND 
        COUNT(*) WHERE swithc=1 AND detail=2 AS onetwo
  FROM tablename
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` Statement in your `SELECT` to get the results:

```
SELECT SUM(case when switch=0 AND detail=1 then 1 else 0 end) as zeroone
    , SUM(case when switch=0 AND detail=2 then 1 else 0 end) as zerotwo
    , SUM(case when switch=1 AND detail=1 then 1 else 0 end) as oneone
    , SUM(case when switch=1 AND detail=2 then 1 else 0 end) as onetw
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    sum(switch=0 AND detail=1) AS zeroone,
    sum(switch=0 AND detail=2) AS zerotwo,
    sum(switch=1 AND detail=1) AS oneone,
    sum(switch=1 AND detail=2) AS onetwo
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN switch = 0 and detail = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS zeroone
     , ...
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you want.

I suppose you want to a select, that returns one row, having 4 columns:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) WHERE switch=0 AND detail=1 AS zeroone,
COUNT(*) WHERE switch=0 AND detail=2 AS zerotwo,
COUNT(*) WHERE switch=1 AND detail=1 AS oneone,
COUNT(*) WHERE swithc=1 AND detail=2 AS onetwo
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you use this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM tablename
 GROUP BY switch, detail
```